# Debugging React-Starter-Kit with WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, isomorphic-javascript

Is it possible to source step the ES6 code for server-side rendering of the react-starter-kit code using WebStorm?

I'm not getting any hits on the break points.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit? To get breakpoints in components hit, I had to add `webpack:///src` for project `src` root:

[image]